# Finding an item in a complex object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a sequence of elements 
**string[]:**

```
new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" }
```

And there is also an object consisting of such several sequences
**object:**

```
List<Test> obj = new List<Test>()
{
    new Test() {Lists = new List<string>() { "A", "B" } },
    new Test() {Lists = new List<string>() { "A", "C" } },
    new Test() {Lists = new List<string>() { "C" } }
};
```

I want to find the missing element (**"D"**) in all object collections.
That's what I got:

```
private static List<string> FindeMissingElements()
{
    string nonExistentElement = null;

    List<string> nonExistentElements = new List<string>();

    foreach (var elemArr in arr)
    {
        foreach (var elemObj in obj)
        {
            if (elemObj.Lists.Any(a => a.Contains(elemArr)))
            {
                nonExistentElement = null;
                break;
            }

            nonExistentElement = elemArr;
        }

        if (nonExistentElement != null)
            nonExistentElements.Add(nonExistentElement);
    }

    return nonExistentElements;
}
```

I would like to simplify the code and use LINQ if possible...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions), not SO

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would flatten the sources into a list so I have a collection of actual values. To do this, it's best to use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (`tests` is the original list, and `domain` is the array of possible elements)

```
var sourceElements = tests.SelectMany(test => test.Lists);
```

This will get the `Lists` properties for each test, and join all the results together, so in your example, you'll have a result of

```
["A", "B", "A", "C", "C"]
```

You can use [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct(v=vs.110).aspx) to only get unique items, so the code is

```
var sourceElements = tests.SelectMany(test => test.Lists).Distinct();
```

Now, the only thing left to do is to find the items that are in the `domain` but not in the `sourceElements`, i.e. their set difference. That can easily be done with the [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
var missing = domain.Except(sourceElements);
```

So, to put everything together, your method should be:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> FindMissingElements(
       IEnumerable<Test> tests, IEnumerable<string> domain)
{
   var sourceElements = tests.SelectMany(test => test.Lists).Distinct();
   var missing = domain.Except(sourceElements)
   return missing;
}
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jh1gmS) is a working example.

Comment: Thank you for a beautiful decision. Can you recommend a book / sites on LIQN?

Answer (score 1):

//Flatten the complex object - Get all the elements from the complex object into an IEnumerable collection
           //Flatten the list --

var listB = (from lm in obj select lm.Lists).SelectMany(it => it.ToList());

//Below list A is input elements
            //use IEnumerable except extension as below - missingElements IEnumerable will have your elements from complex object --

string[] listA = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
            var missinElements = listA.Except(listB);

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: just added some comments

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you:

```
var list1 = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" }
var nonExistentElements = new List<string>(list1);
obj.ForEach(o => nonExistentElements = nonExistentElements.Except(o.Lists).ToList());
```

Comment: And what if one of the lists of the object is null?

Comment: @Tibomso According to the problem logic, null must be returned if null is not your choice list. but if you don't want it, you can omit it as an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I Try and test your question like this:

```
private static List<string> FindeMissingElements()
{
  var objectArray = new[] {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
  var obj = new List<Test>()
  {
    new Test() {Lists = new List<string>() { "A", "B" } },
    new Test() {Lists = new List<string>() { "A", "C" } },
    new Test() {Lists = new List<string>() { "C" } }
  };
    var missingValues = objectArray.Where(x => !obj.Any(c => c.Lists.Any(v => v == x))).ToList();
    return missingValues.any() ? missingValue:missingValue = new List<string>();
}
```

With 1 row you can find missing value.

GoodLuck.